# Connecting QlikSense to a IBMi DB2

Tags: database, db2, qlikview, qliksense

I'm trying to setup a connection between QlikSense and a IBMi DB2 database. the OS version for IBM is 7.3. I'm not sure if the connection can be made with a ODBC driver or if it needs a separate driver installation for the connection. Has someone made an attempt at such a DB connection? THE DB2 instance is one that comes inbuilt with the IBMi server.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of configuration question, you may find preexisting answers and additional help on the [QlikSense community](https://community.qlik.com/) Forum.

A quick glance [there](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Connectivity-Data-Prep/How-to-use-the-native-IBM-DB2-connector-in-Qlik-Sense-to-connect/m-p/54003) suggests that others have had some success, albeit with issues, using the IBM i access product ODBC option.

It's unclear if QlikSense has any formal support for i-series dialect of Db2, but that is something you should ask on that forum.

It's also possible that third party ODBC driver (e.g from Datadirect) may yield a different result from IBM supplied drivers.